# Including In C++

Tags: c++, include

In C++, you have to include certain libraries to use certain commands.
For example, you type `#include <iostream>` in order to use `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

I always forget what to include to use what commands, so I wonder if there is an easy way to remember, or if it's possible to include everything.

Any way to help me and other people out there who has this problem remember the different includes or a way to make including simpler is appreciated!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/ -- Type the function, class or object you want to use in the search bar. The required header should be displayed near the top of the page.

Comment: IDEs solve this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including *everything* would take *forever* to compile so that is not advised.

http://www.cplusplus.com/ can tell you what to include for almost anything you are going to need.

Also, you will start to remember them over time.

Comment: Can you just please give me a list of the common things that programmers use?

Comment: What things have you used in any programs so far? Presumably most people are using those same things...

Comment: What are commonly used by others?

Comment: Just common programs.

Comment: Common programs that fly space ships? Or common programs that run a microwave? or common programs that do arithmetic? You question is so vague; I am going to continue to give you vague answers...

Comment: Common programs that do arithmetic.

Comment: And what can that do?

Answer (score 1):

You can write programs like they are an essay. Take a look at [literate programming](http://www.literateprogramming.com/knuthweb.pdf).

For instance, at the literate programming wiki, you can find a hello world program that addresses all your concerns [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Hello_World_%28C_Plus_Plus%29).

Comment: Good advice, but I don't think that's what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Just do a quick search of the command you're using, and the forum explaining the command should tell you which library/libraries are involved.

Comment: No, that's my problem right now. I don't want to search every time.